# Use both splitActionBarWhenNarrow and ActionBar icons

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

While using `splitActionBarWhenNarrow`, is it possible to put menu items on the action bar (the regular way) ? What i'd like is to put some items on the bottom of the screen and some on the top.

Thanks :)

Comment: Note that `splitActionBarWhenNarrow` is not supported with `Theme.Material` or `Theme.AppCompat`, and so I would not recommend relying upon it long-term. Beyond that, AFAIK, the action bar items would only go on the bottom.

Comment: That's a shame, splitActionBarWhenNarrow is verry esthetic ... i'll find another way then.

Comment: The workaround, such as it is, is to use `Toolbar` to manually put a "split action bar" at the bottom.